Unable to Connect to SignalR Hub from Phone While Computer and Unity Can: C# ASP.NET Core Web App with SignalR
I have developed a C# ASP.NET Core Web App using SignalR for real-time communication. I am running the application on local IIS with a public IP address. On the same network, I am able to access the site from my phone using the public IP address, and of course, I can access it from my computer as well. I can also connect to the SignalR hub from Unity (on my computer) using the same IP address. However, I am unable to connect from my phone(android) to hub with the same unity app, and I am not receiving any error messages.
Note: I also use Conveyor by Keyoti
Why am I unable to connect to the SignalR hub from my phone using the Unity application? How can I troubleshoot this connection issue?

just to confirm: I am confused by I am able to access the site from my phone using the public IP address and then I am unable to connect from my phone(android) .. is that a different phone / different network?

@derHugo " I am unable to connect from my phone(android) to hub"
No, it's the same phone. I can reach the website using the same phone with with same network, but I cannot reach the signal r hub thats run inside of same website  from the same phone with same network

any helps? I really need help

Do you configure and use only specified transports? or enabled all transports?
